# Push from master branch to main and delete master

Tags: git

I accidentally created a new branch called master, now the project has two branches, `main` and `master`, every push and commit goes to `master` and I want to stay on the initial `main` branch.

Running `git show-ref` result:

```
...07c086 refs/heads/master
...109376 refs/remotes/origin/main
```

I tried `git push origin : main` to push from `master` to `main`:

```
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://URL'
```

**EDIT**

I can go back or undo previous commits while I was on the same initial branch using `git reflog` and then `git reset --hard TO_Some_Point` but when trying to commit again, it creates a new branch automatically(In vscode it shows publish to branch) and commit to that branch!

**EDIT 2**

This is the weird output of my `git push` that resulted in creating a new branch for unknown reason:

```
git push
Enumerating objects: 161, done.
Counting objects: 100% (161/161), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (104/104), done.
Writing objects: 100% (117/117), 47.18 KiB | 5.24 MiB/s, done.
Total 117 (delta 63), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (63/63), completed with 28 local objects.
remote: 
remote: Create a pull request for 'master' on GitHub by visiting:
remote:      https://URL/pull/new/master
remote: 
To https://URL
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

How to fix this and eventually delete `master` branch?

Comment: You don't *have* a `main` branch. There's no requirement that the branch names in your repository match those in any other repository. In fact, you don't *have to* use branch names at all, to use Git. It's just that trying to work that way is crazy (don't do it). Note that the syntax here is `git push origin main` (no colon), or if you want to use the name `xyzzy` locally and the name `fred` in the remote, `git push origin xyzzy:fred` for instance (and now the colon springs into play).

Comment: *Probably*, what you want to do is replace the existing `master` commits you made with new and improved commits that append to the commits that are reachable in your own repository through the name `origin/main` at the moment. Alternatively, if those `origin/main` commits are useless and you want to forget about them, you can *rename* your existing `master` to call it `main`, send your own `main` commits to `origin`, and force the Git on `origin` to discard its existing commits in favor of yours instead.

Comment: The *first* step, though, is to understand that Git doesn't *really* care about *branch names* at all. Git cares only about the *commits*, with the names being ways that Git lets us (humans) find the commits without having to memorize those big ugly random-looking hash IDs.

Comment: @torek Thanks for useful comments, the repository now has two branches, and I can not reach other collaborators commits neither they can reach mine's, so what should we do?

Comment: It's hard to know for sure without actual access to your repository, but it's *probable* that you can rebase your commits onto a new `main` you create with `git switch main`, which will create the name `main` in your own repository at the same commit that you have as `origin/main` in your own repository. That is: you'd run `git fetch` to update, then `git switch main` to create a new name `main`, then `git switch master`, then `git rebase main`. (This is a bit of a long way around, but may make visualizing what's going on easier.)

Comment: If and when this all finishes successfully, you'd *rename* this `master` to `feature` or whatever other name you want to call it, and then do stuff that depends on what your normal feature-integration workflow might be.